# Implicit conversion to const of dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c++, constants

In the following code, a class owns a dynamically-allocated array. It exposes a read-only access to this array via a public method that does an implicit conversion to `const`.

```
#include <array>

template <class T, std::size_t N>
class A {
  const unsigned int size;
  std::array<T, N> *s;
public:
  A(const unsigned int _size, const std::array<T, N>& def) :
     size(_size),
     s(new std::array<T, N>[size])
  {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      s[i] = def;
  }
  ~A() { delete[] s; }

  std::array<T, N> const* const conf() const { return s; }
};

int main()
{
  A a(10, std::array<int, 3>{0, 0, 0});
  auto x = a.conf();
  return 0;
}
```

Does the implicit const conversion in `A::conf()` give rise to an overhead (for example by invoking a copy-constructor of the elements of `A::s`)?

Comment: I think that you redesign your code as it is half encapsulated. You hide memory management but not the fact that you have an array. At least, using `std::vector` instead of C style array, you would get `size`, iterators and more.

Comment: Another problem with your code is that it does not follows the rule of 5. For example, copy construction of `A` will lead to disaster.

Comment: @Phil1970 I agree, but adding the required copy constructor would not change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the implicit const conversion in A::conf() give rise to an overhead (for example by invoking a copy-constructor of the elements of A::s)?

*No*.

There is no *"overhead"*, a pointer can be implicitly converted in its `const`-version. Generally, the conversion generates zero assembly instruction.

---

### Additional Notes

#### Empirical Proof

`A::conf()` does not call any *copy-constructor*. From the generated assembly (`gcc -O3`):

```
A<int, 3ul>::conf() const:
        movq    %rdi, %rax
        ret
```

As you can see, it just returns the pointer without producing any further instructions.

*Note: I disabled the "inlining optimization" here, otherwise the entire function would be optimized producing zero overhead.*

#### Small Tips

- Maybe a little bit off-topic, but it is good practice to avoid managing raw memory in modern C++ (whenever possible).
  What about using `std::vector`?
- In the signature `std::array<T, N> const* const conf() const` the second `const` is always ignored by the compiler. You can omit making it more readable: `std::array<T, N> const* conf() const`.

Comment: I would be careful about "proving" things using (optimized) assembly. You have to hide the right things from the compiler (e.g. the constructor body here) or look at the unoptimized code. Even then you can never be sure about compiler bugs (this is of course a very trivial case). Still, good answer!

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Actually, I've inspected the unoptimized assembly as well. Of course, there was no copy-constructor call. However, I didn't report it because the unoptimized assemble version is too long in the scope of this simple question/answer. I think the real problem is the meaning of `proof`. There is no point in proving something referring to the implementation (compiler). The real proof can only be lead by the standard. I am going to update the section with a more appropriate title, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`conf()` returns a pointer (`std::array<T, N> const*`). Thus `auto x = a.conf();` deduces the type of x to be a const pointer `std::array<T, N> const*`. The address/pointer is copied by value (typically copy 4byte/8byte address depending on your system). No c'tor is called.